# Crear un dominio web

Tags: html, web, dominio, localhost

Tengo una pagina web creada en modo local, y me gustaría subirla a la web.

¿Alguien me puede decir cual es la mejor forma para realizar esta operación? y también subir la base de datos.

Gracias a todos de antemano

Un saludo.

Comment: Puede que este no sea el sitio adecuado para esta pregunta, pero si das más información puede que alguien te pueda ayudar: ¿Qué tipo de base de datos? ¿qué tipo de entorno de programación? ¿es un proyecto personal y quieres algo gratuito o bien de pago?

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre, por favor considera leer [ask] y de paso checa el [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Primero. Necesitas saber que es una dirección Ip [Aca te dejo este enlace para que te enteres mejor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direcci%C3%B3n_IP) , en pocas palabras una dirección Ip es un número de 4 dígitos separados por 1 punto y existen diferentes tipos de dirección Ip, ya te dejo más investigación a ti. Por ejemplo 172.217.30.196 es la dirección Ip de google, pero gracias al protocolo DNS, [Por aca te dejo otro link que te explicara como funciona](https://definicion.de/dns/), podemos convertir esos números en un nombre por el cual podemos identificar más fácil una pagina web, y asi sabes que puedes buscar www.google.com, pero en realidad detrás de todo se traduce a 172.217.30.196.

  - Segundo. Necesitas de un Hosting [Por aca te dejo un enlace que te explicara brevemente lo que es](https://www.hostinger.co/tutoriales/que-es-un-hosting), en pocas palabras El Hosting es un servicio en línea que te permite publicar un sitio o aplicación web en Internet. Esté mantendrá tu web disponible las 24 horas del día, obviamente tienes que pagar por eso.
  - Tercero. Tal vez te estés preguntando, ¿cómo puedo llegar a juntar todo esto? [Por aca te dejare un video que lo explica brevemente](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vA1PiXEK4Os), el video no es mio.
  - Otra opción, es conseguir un Dominio y servicio de Hosting gratuito, peor no es muy recomendable, ya que puede ser muy inestable o llegar a caerse en algún momento.

Comment: Si deseas aprender a alojar tu sitio web de forma gratuita y como conectarlo con tu dominio a través de un registrador de dominios y actualizando el DNS. Este tutorial te enseña todo lo que necesitas incluyendo como funciona el internet y varias opciones alternativas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wOhVltQ7lM